# Let $M$ be a maximal ideal of a ring R. Let $ I \subset M$ prove that $M \neq M_c $ for any c $\in R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

where,

$R=${$f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}|$ f is continuous}

$M_c=${$f \in R|$ $f(c)=0$}

$I=${$f \in R |$ f has a compact support}.

I have proved that $I$ is an Ideal.

I thought of a this question as contradiction

let $M=M_c$  for a fixed c $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$
and
$f(x)=$$\begin{cases} 1- \frac{c-x}{\delta}, x\in[c-\delta,c)\\
1- \frac{x-c}{\delta}, x\in[c,c+\delta]\\
0, otherwise\end{cases}$

since $f(x)$ has compact support and $f(x)$ is continuous $\implies$ $f(x) \in I$

since $I \subset M$ $ \implies f(x) \in M$

Which is a contadiction to our assumption.

I don't know i am totally correct or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is "correct", although honestly the argument is not well understood. Here I give you a direct proof with a cleaner writing; notice that it is not very different from yours.

Let $c \in \Bbb R$. In order to prove that $M \neq M_c$, it suffices to find $f \in M$ such that $f(c) \neq 0$ (if every function in $M$ vanishes at $c$, then $M \subseteq M_c$, from which follows that $M=M_c$ by maximality of $M$).

Indeed, define $f \colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ by $$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
1-|x-c| & \textrm{if } x \in [c-1,c+1], \\
0 & \textrm{if not.}
\end{cases}
$$ Clearly, $f$ is continuous and has compact support (namely, $[c-1,c+1]$), so $f \in I$. Since $I \subseteq M$, then $f \in M$. Moreover, $f(c) =1$.